# mysql: Media Wiki Extension problem (blank page)

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

I am using a Media wiki that is hosted on a MySQL server.

Successfully installed some extensions.

Now I tried that again (install into my extension folder and add it into my local settings as I always did) but now when I open my wiki I get this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Unable to open file (and then the
> file)

I tried: to unpack the files with different applications, name them differently, tried do install an old version.

Don't know where to look for other ideas so maybe someone can help.

Comment: maybe file permission problem? did this solve your problem: ```chmod -R 777 mediawiki_install_path/images``` and ```chmod -R 777 mediawiki_install_path/upload```

Comment: Thanks Kristian, but i don't really know anything about programming. Where should i copy that into? into my Localsettings, no?

Comment: @Kristian, the problem seems to be with the `extensions` folder, not `uploads`. @IngmarH, you should learn how to connect to your server's terminal, if you have access to it. `chmod` is done there, though `chown -R www-data mediawiki_install_path/extensions` seems to be a better choice, provided that the web server runs under that user. Also, you will be able to install and upgrade your MediaWiki and the extensions with git.

Comment: Well, my comment above is just trying to probe the problem. I'm not even sure if its because of file permission (assuming the OP even use linux/unix host). So if the problem is solved by chmod 777 then we can assume it is unix file permission problem and give correct solution later.

Comment: @IngmarH How do you install the mediawiki? Shared hosting? VPS? cPanel? FTP? SSH? What operating system is used on the host? Please describe what steps you're taking to install it